# Looking for example of an axis for which axis.tickSubdivide() makes a difference

Tags: d3.js

Can someone show me an example in which the method `axis.tickSubdivide` makes a difference?

---

I have not been able to find such an example.  IOW, whatever example I've come up with, whether or not I include a call to `tickSubdivide` I get the same result, and when I do include a call to `tickSubdivide`, I get the same result irrespective of the value that I pass to it (as long as I pass *some* value).

---

When I look at the source code, it seems to be a no-op:

```
axis.tickSubdivide = function() {
  return arguments.length && axis;
};
```

...but I can't claim to understand the `d3` source code.

(FWIW, the above shows the only mention of the substring string `ubdivide` in the file `d3.v3.js`, as downloaded today from d3js.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It doesn't do anything!](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/f59fc64a20d57fe08be9fb6e53ab0022f6f6c732/test/svg/axis-test.js)

```
"tickSubdivide": {
  "is deprecated and does nothing": function(d3) {
```

As for:

```
return arguments.length && axis;
```

From [MDN, the definition of &&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
expr1 && expr2
Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2.
```

`axis.tickSubdivide()` will return 0 since arguments.length is equal to 0 which is falsy in javascript. If there are more arguments passed -  `axis.tickSubdivide('atLeastOneArg')` - it will return `axis`. See [Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) for more about this convention.